# How to convert text to date entered as a date in sql?

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services, type-conversion

Data type is TEXT and entered as '20/11/2017' and when using MAX or MIN it ignores the month. I am trying to convert it into a date format for month to be considered as well.

CAST AND CONVERT do not seem to work as the following error returns

> Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 13
>   Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

Code:

```
SELECT     
    user_id, 
    record_id
    --CAST(onSale AS date) AS onSale
    --CONVERT(DATE, onSale) AS onSale, 
    --CONVERT(DATE, OffSale) AS OffSale
FROM (SELECT  user_id, 
             record_id,
             (SELECT MAX(value) AS Expr1
             FROM      UPLOADS.LINES AS SUH WITH (NoLock, ReadUncommitted)
             WHERE  (field_id = 4782) AND (record_id = UR.record_id)) AS onSale,
             (SELECT MAX(value) AS Expr1
             FROM      UPLOADS.LINES AS SUH WITH (NoLock, ReadUncommitted)
             WHERE  (field_id = 4783) AND (record_id = UR.record_id)) AS OffSale
        FROM   UPLOADS.RECORDS AS UR WITH (NoLock, ReadUncommitted)
        WHERE      (module_id = 18)) AS DATA;
```

The end result would essentially be the MAX or MIN date with all three components being date,month and year. So if the user has entered two dates being 17/05/2018 and 17/04/2018 then the first should be shown if MAX is used.

Comment: You need to SET DATEFORMAT dmy;  before you run the query. That should persuade SQL Server to use uk date format, thus letting CAST or CONVERT work

Comment: `ntext`, `text`, and `image` data types will be removed in a future version of SQL Server. Avoid using these data types in new development work, and plan to modify applications that currently use them. Use `nvarchar(max)`, `varchar(max)`, and `varbinary(max)` instead. [See details here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187993.aspx). And to store a **DATE** - you should ***REALLY*** use `DATE` or `DATETIME2(n)` - not any string based datatype!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a format code when using CONVERT, and you can even use TRY_CONVERT to prevent errors from invalid dates. I also improved your code to make it simpler and more efficient.

```
SELECT  [user_id], 
        record_id,
        MAX(CASE WHEN SUH.field_id = 4782 THEN TRY_CONVERT( DATE, SUH.value, 103) END) AS onSale,
        MAX(CASE WHEN SUH.field_id = 4783 THEN TRY_CONVERT( DATE, SUH.value, 103) END) AS OffSale
FROM  UPLOADS.RECORDS AS UR 
JOIN  UPLOADS.LINES AS SUH ON SUH.record_id = UR.record_id
WHERE  module_id = 18
GROUP BY [user_id], 
        record_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a slight improvement on Luis's answer in terms of the SQL:

```
SELECT ur.[user_id], ur.record_id,
       MAX(CASE WHEN SUH.field_id = 4782 THEN TRY_CONVERT( DATE, SUH.value, 103) END) AS onSale,
       MAX(CASE WHEN SUH.field_id = 4783 THEN TRY_CONVERT( DATE, SUH.value, 103) END) AS OffSale
FROM  UPLOADS.RECORDS UR LEFT JOIN
      UPLOADS.LINES AS SUH
      ON SUH.record_id = UR.record_id AND
         SUH.field_id IN (4782, 4783)
WHERE ur.module_id = 18
GROUP BY ur.[user_id], ur.record_id;
```

That said, your problem is that your data is not in the format you think it is.  Hence, the problem with type conversions.  As @marc_s says in a comment, you should be using SQL native and appropriate types which in this case is `DATE`.  And you certainly should not be using deprecated types, such as `TEXT` (unless you really just mean `VARCHAR()` and don't realize that there is a deprecated `TEXT` type).  If you are storing values in strings (because there are different types), you should use the standard format, either YYYYMMDD or YYYY-MM-DD.

You can find these values by running:

```
select suh.value
from uploads.lines suh
where suh.field_id in (4782, 4783) and
      try_convert(date, suh.value, 103) is null and
      suh.value is not null;
```

This can help you fix your data.

After you have fixed your data, you can also fix the type:

```
update uploads.lines
    set suh.value = convert(varchar(255), convert(date, suh.value, 103), 112);  -- this will convert the value to the default date format
```